# Wrong direction of dragging trajectory line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

Wrong direction of dragging trajectory line

I was tring to make a preview fire line for aim.
This pic showed it's work fine facing toward.
[image]

But the trajectory line is facing to a wrong direction when I drag it on other direction.
[image]

Below is the code I done.

line is the LineRenderer I'm using.

velocity is the force calculated to shoot.(rigibody.addFroce(velocity))

Because the object is a child under player, I had tried use transform.Position but the LineRenderer will moved to somewhere else. So I had to use localPosition instead, not sure does this affect anything in the calculation.

```
public void ShowLine(Vector3 velocity)
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        float timeStep = lineTime / lineCount;
        Vector3 pos = transform.localPosition;
        line.SetPosition(0, pos);
        for (int i = 1; i < line.positionCount; i++)
        {
            float timeOffset = timeStep * i;
            Vector3 progress = velocity * timeOffset;
            Vector3 gravity = Vector3.up * -0.5f * Physics.gravity.y * timeOffset * timeOffset;
            pos = transform.localPosition + progress - gravity;
            line.SetPosition(i, pos);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your calcs for line position are pretty convoluted; there's likely a simpler way. What are you trying to achieve exactly, in terms of there the aim should be? Also, you probably do want world space (`position`, not `localPosition`).

Comment: I had a line of mouse drag as the input, my object did fly as what input did. But the preview fireline didn't showed the direction same as input mouse drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I had solved myself after more work.

Just gonna put on here maybe it will help someone.

force is the force going to apply to rigibody.AddForce

line is the LineRenderer component

I should use Vector3[] to store the result for LineRenderer.SetPositions

But it's just personal preference that I prefer using List

```
public void ShowLine(Vector3 force)
{
    line.enabled = true;
    List<Vector3> lineList = new List<Vector3>();
    lineList.Add(transform.position);
    Vector3 velocity = rigi.velocity + ((force / rigi.mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i)
    {
        float dt = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Vector3 aDt = Physics.gravity * dt;
        float dragDt = 1 - rigi.drag * dt;
        if (dragDt < 0)
        {
            dragDt = 0;
        }
        Vector3 acc = 0.5f * dt * dt * Physics.gravity;
        for (int j = 0; j < lineTimeGap; ++j)
        {
            velocity = (velocity + aDt) * dragDt;
            pos = pos + velocity * dt + acc;
        }
        lineList.Add(pos);
    }
    line.positionCount = lineList.Count();
    line.SetPositions(lineList.ToArray());
}
```